# File attachment control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to attach a file from my C# code. I want a user interface from there user can easily select their file. What is scene of code or control in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of application: WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, ...?

Comment: Window Program. I am with WinForm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [OpenFileDialog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/RPattinson/OpenFileDialog06092009185116PM/OpenFileDialog.aspx) class for this.

It displays a nice dialog box where the user can select his file, and you can get the filename in return. It also supports filtering for different file types.

**EDIT**

I initially wrote `FileDialog`, but `OpenFileDialog` is of course the best one.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class?